# Three column Bootstrap layout with left sidebar at bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve a three-column layout with Bootstrap 3. I want the page to appear like on left part of the image while on a desktop and like on the image to the right when on mobile.

```
<aside class="left col-md-2"></aside>   
<div class="left col-md-7"></div>
<aside class="left col-md-3"></aside>
```

Any help?

[image]

Comment: `pull-left` is your huckleberry. The document should be structured with the most important content at the top. Presentation is handled separately.

Comment: That said, please show us your markup attempt. The question is off-topic as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the div as your first container followed by the asides and then use `col-lg-push-*` and `col-lg-pull-*` to switch on larger device. [`Source here`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering)

**Demo** [Click on Full Page of the snippet to test for larger device]

```css
div,aside { height: 50px}
.content { background: lightpink;}
.side1 { background: lightblue;}
.side2 { background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="content left col-md-7 col-lg-push-2"></div>
  <aside class="side1 left col-md-2 col-lg-pull-7"></aside>
  <aside class="side2 left col-md-3"></aside>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this almost works but not completely. Even in your own example there is a certain size before the pull happens when the two aside are one beside the other. Can you check it?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Can you explain exactly what the issue is? Are you saying that at a certain size the asides are still with each other?

Comment: When resizing the browser at around 1200px width, the left aside runs to the right side just besides the right aside. You can check it on your own example. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100675/bootstrap-glitch-in-pull-push

Comment: Oh ok. I have used `col-lg-*` and hence it starts only when the size is having min-width of 1200px. You can change that to `col-md-push-*` and `col-md-pull-*`like this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Len0q7uq/light/). Hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="col-xs-12 visible-xs">Middle Column</div>

<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12">Left column</div>
<div class="col-lg-8 hidden-xs">Middle column</div>
<div class="col-lg-2 col-xs-12">Right column</div>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would avoid duplicating the middle column as it *very* busy and full of all the main content of the page.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="col1" class="col-md-4">col-md-1</div>
  <div id="col2" class="col-md-4">col-md-2</div>
  <div id="col3" class="col-md-4">col-md-3</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#col1 {background-color: blue;}
#col2 {background-color: purple;}
#col3 {background-color: green;}

#col1 {display:table-footer-group;}
#col2 {display:table-header-group;}
#col3 {display:table;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/909ecqbb/)