# Bootstrap glitch in pull / push

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

starting from this question [Three column Bootstrap layout with left sidebar at bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081657/three-column-bootstrap-layout-with-left-sidebar-at-bottom) I learned about Bootstrap column push and pull.

The snippet below almost works in getting the result I want:

[image]

The problem is the resizing the screen, at around 1200px width the two `aside` elements (blue and green) are one beside the other (you can check the snippet).

Any help?

```css
div,aside { height: 50px}
.content { background: lightpink;}
.side1 { background: lightblue;}
.side2 { background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="content left col-md-7 col-lg-push-2"></div>
  <aside class="side1 left col-md-2 col-lg-pull-7"></aside>
  <aside class="side2 left col-md-3"></aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a glitch. You're mixing sizes. Your pushes and pulls should be set at the same breakpoint as the column declarations.

```css
div,aside { height: 50px}
.content { background: lightpink;}
.side1 { background: lightblue;}
.side2 { background: lightgreen;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="content left col-md-7 col-md-push-2"></div>
  <aside class="side1 left col-md-2 col-md-pull-7"></aside>
  <aside class="side2 left col-md-3"></aside>
</div>
```